# Jquery backup for HTML5's autofocus feature to ensure autofocus in all browsers

Tags: jquery, html, autofocus

```
<textarea type="text" id="message" rows="1" cols="20" name="email" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autofocus required></textarea>
```

Is there some Jquery that I can implement to ensure that browsers that do not support HTML5 autofocus still autofocus on this textarea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/):

```
$(function() {
    $("#message").focus();
});
```

Comment: @user852974 -  Pfft - stupid IE.  I'm not sure.  Are you focusing some other input that's canceling this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
       if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
         $("#message").focus();
         //document.getElementById('message').focus(); as an alternitive.
       }
    });
 </script>
```

Will work and not fire for those browsers that support autofocus.

Code gratuitously stolen from [diveintohtml5.info](http://diveintohtml.info/forms.html#autofocus)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(function() {
    $("#message").focusin();
});
```